# run all .bach in a folder and sub-folders

Tags: linux, jobs

I have a folder with many sub-folders and sub-sub-folders.
All .bach files have the same name --> R_batch_1_1.bash

Usually I use:
`sbatch  R_batch_1_1.bash` to run one by one.

Does anyone know how to do this in once time for all the .bach in the folder and sub-folders?

Answer (score 1):

you can find all files in sub-directories and run them with:

```
find yourdirectory/ -name "R_batch_1_1.bash" -type f | xargs sbatch
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For same reason it is not working, In each sub-folder that is located the R_batch_1_1.bash there is also others files that are executed from the R_batch_1_1.bach file. Do you think it may be related with the problem?

Comment: I think so! you must `cd` to the location of the file and then run it! I recommend write a bash script to find folder which contains the file in a loop, `cd` to that folder and run it. However, there maybe some other methods to change current directory when running bash scripts.